# Почему css применённый к js корректно работает в Фаерфоксе, но некорректно в Гугл хроме?

Tags: javascript, css, tilda

Привет всем) я не шарю в коде, поэтому решил спросить у вас. Делаю сайт на Тильде, добавляю готовую анимацию (дисторшен при наведении) в круглый шейп, куда прокидывается круглая пнг фотография. Дело в том, что код видимо создаёт канвас, который квадрат, что для меня неприемлимо, так как вокруг круглой фотографии у меня вертится текст.

Я применил такой стиль к канвасу
`<style> canvas{ border-radius: 50% !important; } </style>`

В итоге в фаерфоксе всё работает гуд
В гугл хроме по прежнему квадрат НО если зайти в режим разработчика, то что-то обновляется и показывается круг как и должно. Есть идеи как исправить отображение в гугл хроме?

Сайт вот, элемент к которому применяется эффект находится в самом низу страницы http://project2884572.tilda.ws/
[image: Проблема]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это похоже старый баг. Чинится добавлением свойства канвасу:

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac/12336233#12336233

Comment: Вы помогли решить мне проблему, над которой я сидел часов 20, учитывая что я  понимаю код только по наитию)) посылаю всевозможные лучи добра